# What magic items are there to capture or restrain someone?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

I'm looking for items to specifically address the strengths and weaknesses of the PC's.

For example, our wizard who has lots of teleport spells will be restrained with [Dimensional Shackles](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=11).

How can I best restrain, for example, our high-strength fighter and our high-dex ranger, outside of typical mundane methods (ropes, shackles, cages, etc)? Are there any magic items to do this?

This should be for an extended period of time (being transported in a wagon, for example), not during combat.

Criteria for "capturing" a PC:

- Effect doesn't end on a save
- One of the following conditions is imposed:

  - Restrained
  - Immobilized
  - Slowed
  - Cannot attack
  - Unconscious
  - Stunned
  - Dazed
  - Misc negative effects (cannot teleport, cannot run, who knows what else is out there...)

Comment: @dpatch - how captured do they have to be? I assume simple rope or a cage trap is out of the equation?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for magic items. I'm not interested in mundane means of capturing or restraining someone (rope, shackles, cages, etc)

Comment: Why the downvote? Please comment or suggest edits (already edited to look for a "best" answer instead of a list) if you think they are necessary.

Comment: @dpatchery That doesn't fully answer the question. Are you looking to be able to pick the helpless PCs up and haul them to jail, or just apply the immobilized condition? (not related to downvote)

Comment: @Ace Since I don't know what magic items are out there, I'm purposefully being a little vague. If there is a magic item to immobilize someone until it is removed, great. But maybe there's something that pacifies the target until it's removed, I don't know. I'll see if I can edit to make that make sense.

Comment: Every item I have found has a "save ends", or requires you to attack the opponent to have it activate, except for poisons.  I suggest creating your own home-brew magic shackles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are extraordinarily few effects that last past a short rest. There are extraordinarily few effects *for a PC*. However, the magic of 4e is that monsters do not use the same magic items, skills, or plot macguffins as a PC.

The most effective PC MacGuffin is the Executioner Assassin's Carrion Crawler Brain Juice. This Executioner only poison that takes the place of one of their daily powers:

> Power (Consumable * Poison): Minor Action. You apply the poison to a single handheld object. Within the next hour, the first creature other than you to hold or wear the object for more than 1 minute is immobilized until the end of its next extended rest.

While this doesn't prevent teleportation, a Dimensional Anchor neatly solves that problem: Property: Any creature within 10 squares of this statue can’t teleport.

The act of applying this poison and the use of this statue, while effective and almost impossible for PCs to combat, completely destroys their agency. It is far more effective to get them in a "teleportation trap" (some sort of handwavy trap/almost-completed ritual) or equivalent instant transport that doesn't involve

"you put on your armor like normal, right?"

"Yeah...?"

"Okay, well, you're immobilized until you sleep next, which can't happen for another 16 hours."

A teleportation trap accomplishes the same thing, but doesn't actively interfere with the player's character's interactions with themselves and their own mental models.

Comment: I like the dimensional anchor! That poison is way too much though.

Comment: Er, yes, yes it is? But hey, it's PC-enabled plot-poison. :) As an NPC, feel free to make struggling out of the poison a skill challenge.